# Google Analytics for separate website in folder

Tags: google-analytics

We have a website, `www.example.com` which has Google Analytics installed.

We have another website, `www.example2.com` which has it's own separate Analytics tracking code.

We are rebranding and moving `www.example2.com` so that instead of being on its own domain, it will simply work from inside a folder of `www.example.com` - for example `www.example.com/example2`

If we want to set up Analytics for `example2`  what is the best way to do this? Two appraoches come to mind:

1. Put the Analytics code for `www.example.com` on to `www.example.com/example2`. Use Analytics to segment traffic that contains `/example2` (and anything following it) in the url.
2. Generate another Analytics tracking code for `www.example.com/example2` - I'm not actually sure whether this can be done.

I believe Google considers both sites as "one website" due to this folder set up?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is whether you need historical data for example2.com. If you need historical data for easy comparisons, then you should probably keep the old UA tracker for the sub folder and maintain the data flow. Even If not, [implementing multiple trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers) for example2 sub folder seems like the best solution. Then you'll have both options available.

Comment: So do you mean change the 'Default URL' to `www.example.com/example2` on the existing Analytics Property for `www.example2.com`? That way we would retain the historical data (that would be good) and Analytics would still be treating them as 2 separate properties?

Comment: No need to change anything in GA interface. You will still have the same 2 properties, the one belonging to example2 will still receive data, but only from users entering example2 sub folder. The master account will record all the traffic, including the sub folder (which you can segment or create a different view for). You just need to add the extra tracker (example2 UA-xxxx-xx)  to all pages under this sub folder